# TypeError concatenating Timestamp and 'datetime.time'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting an error while concatenating a `'date'` and `'hour'` column.  I have formatted the `'hour'` column to display `'22:00'` instead of `'22'` prior to the concat function.

What's wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Pertinent code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(path)
dataset['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['date'])
dataset['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['hour'], format='%H').dt.time
dataset['datetime'] = pd.concat(dataset['date'] + dataset['hour'])
```

I've also tried `pd.combine` and I get the same error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'datetime.time'
```

Comment: Post sample data

Comment: 'date' sample: '2011-01-02'    'hour' sample: 00 through 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this too:

```
dataset['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(dataset.date.astype(str)+' '+dataset.hour.astype(str)+':00:00')

#if your dataset looks like:
#       date          hour
#0     2018-01-01     5
#1     2018-01-01     10
#2     2018-01-01     0
```

Or this:

```
dataset['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(dataset.date.astype(str)+' '+dataset.hour.astype(str)+':00')

#if your dataset looks like:
#       date          hour
#0     2018-01-01     05:00
#1     2018-01-01     10:00
#2     2018-01-01     00:00
```

Comment: Thanks again.  Good to see you.   ヘ( ^o^)ノ＼(^_^ )